# C# ASP MVC pulling data from the web config file is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to pull data from the web config file as outlined by this [msdn resource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/610xe886.aspx).

Here is my code:

```
System.Configuration.Configuration activeCampaignApiSetting1 =
  System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(null);
if (activeCampaignApiSetting1.AppSettings.Settings.Count > 0) {
    System.Configuration.KeyValueConfigurationElement activeCampaignApiKeySetting =
      activeCampaignApiSetting1.AppSettings.Settings["ActiveCampaignApiKey"];
    if (activeCampaignApiKeySetting != null) {
        activeCampaignApiKey = activeCampaignApiKeySetting.Value;
    }

    System.Configuration.KeyValueConfigurationElement activeCamapignApiUrlSetting =
      activeCampaignApiSetting1.AppSettings.Settings["ActiveCampaignApiUrl"];
    if (activeCamapignApiUrlSetting != null) {
        activeCampaignApiUrl = activeCamapignApiUrlSetting.Value;
    }
}
```

When I try to instantiate this class:

```
var acs = new Acs(activeCampaignApiKey, activeCampaignApiUrl);
```

it throws an exception telling me that the values are blank.

The values in the web config file are there:

```
<add key="ActiveCampaignApiKey" value="apikey_removed" />
<add key="ActiveCampaignApiUrl" value="apiurl_removed" />
```

Anyone know where I may be going wrong?
Cheers

Comment: Try to use AppSettings["ActiveCampaignApiUrl"]. Omit the call to .Settings.

Comment: @Vlad HI, I get the red squiggle line with this error: configuration element is inaccessible due to it's pretection level. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: To be honest I've never used the API from MSDN article. Here's what I've been using for years: System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["your key"]. Could you try that?

Comment: Figured it out @Vlad see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I have a better solution,

As I'm working with nopCommerce I need to use:

```
private readonly ISettingService _settingService = EngineContext.Current.Resolve<ISettingService>();

string apikey = _settingService.GetSettingByKey<string>("apikey_removed");
string apiurl = _settingService.GetSettingByKey<string>("apiurl_removed");
```

As outlined in this [forum thread](https://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/t/15574/all-settings-in-configuration.aspx)

Then in the administration backend under configuration > settings > all settings I add the key there.

This is a much better solution because if the api key or url ever need to be changed it can be done through the nopcommerce administration panel. rather than rebuilding/publishing the solution to a web server.

Hope this helps someone :)

Answer (score 5):

If they are appSetting inside web.config, you can access them via `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings`.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
   <configSections>
      <appSettings>
         <add key="ActiveCampaignApiKey" value="apikey_removed" />
         <add key="ActiveCampaignApiUrl" value="apiurl_removed" />
      </appSettings>
   </configSections>
</configuration>

string activeCampaignApiKeySetting 
 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ActiveCampaignApiKey"];

string activeCamapignApiUrlSetting 
 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ActiveCampaignApiUrl"];
```

Please make sure you reference `System.Configuration`, and include `using System.Configuration;` [directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive).

*FYI: They return string value (not key value pair).*

Comment: Ok figured out a better way of doing this. See my answer. Upvote for your solution as it will work also. THanks for the help :)